# jquery - Loop through array of select fields with different array keys

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, loops

I am generating some select inputs dynamically, and it follows this structure

```
<select id="OrderType_orderItem_0_product" name="OrderType[orderItem][0][product]" class="form-control">,

<select id="OrderType_orderItem_1_product" name="OrderType[orderItem][1][product]" class="form-control">
```

and so on.

I need to do a ajax post on .change on every select generated, how can I do that?

Right now I have this, but it obviously just work for the first select of id 0:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[name="OrderType[orderItem][0][product]"]').change(function(){
           var val = $(this).val();
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myurl" + val,
                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Delete the Javascript tag.

Comment: Been a while, but I believe to bind events onto dynamically created elements you have to use a [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

Comment: Depends on when they're created, but it's a valid point.  Are these elements created on the server or client?

Comment: @DrewKennedy delegate worked. I did $("body").on("change", "select[name^='[OrderType]']", function(){ //stuff });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to trigger function on `change` of any select input that's name's start with `OrderType`

Try this exemple :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("select[name^='OrderType']").change(function(){

           var val = $(this).val();

           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myurl" + val,
                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
            return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: this works only on the first select, do you know why?

Comment: No it's works here is an example please check the console https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/544521/

Comment: Actually I had to do: $("body").on("change", "select[name^='[OrderType]']", function(){}); since the jquery wasn't working in the dynamic added elements, but with this delegate method it worked.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this would be to give them a shared class

```
<select id="OrderType_orderItem_0_product" name="OrderType[orderItem][0][product]" class="form-control myClass">,

<select id="OrderType_orderItem_1_product" name="OrderType[orderItem][1][product]" class="form-control myClass">
```

And then assigning this event to that class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myClass').change(function(){
           var val = $(this).val();
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myurl" + val,
                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

because we are using this element for val it will use the element that has triggered the event.